# prevent requests to o-o---preferred---bellcanada-yul2---v21---cache.c.pack.google.com

Tags: internet-connection

I have a very slow connection and I use to check constantly what requests i made to save bandwidth, I have noticed that i can't open IE or Chrome, they don't stop of doing request to o-o---preferred---bellcanada-yul2---v21---cache.c.pack.google.com, they download some bytes the request ends and then process repeats forever.

What can I do to avoid this? it's really burning my bandwidth,

**update**

I am using windows 7 and navigating behind a proxy using modem, i want to totally avoid this request or future urls if they appear.

thanks.

Comment: I can't flesh this out into a proper answer at the moment, but for chrome  you can try looking at the "AdBlockPlus" addon, and blacklist the domain.

Answer (score 0):

(“Burning” your bandwidth? How much data is being transferred and how often?)

The request is checking for an update to Chrome (the BellCanada part is probably your ISP’s caching proxy).

You can [disable Chrome’s autoupdate function](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates).